# How to prevent special fonts to insert in WordPress post publishing

Tags: php, wordpress

On my blog/article posting website in WordPress, some users post special fonts/characters.. Like

"**Indrė Leonavičiūtė Talks About UX for the Blockchain**" 
If user inserting this above line in Title of post, then i want to validate for ***Leonavičiūtė***,

I have found this Wordpress function remove_accents( string $string )
But how to apply this in on content?

[Example how is showing its](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VQwG.png)

I need to add a validation on wp-admin post submitting, to prevent its.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function filter_handler($data , $postarr) {
  $data_title=$data['post_title'];
  $filtered_title = remove_accents( $data_title );
  $data['post_title']=$filtered_title;
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_handler', '99', 2 );
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a description of how this solves the problem, rather than dumping code.

Answer (score 2):

use the content filter like this

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  remove_accents( $content );
  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: Hi @RST This not working , because $content is a array and remove_accents( string $string ) will work with string. I have tried this also but something wen wrong, unfortunately not updating post..                                 function filter_accents($post_ID, $data){
$post_title = $data->post_title;
$filtered_title = remove_accents($post_title);
$data->post_title = $filtered_title;
return $data;
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'filter_accents',1, 2);

Comment: I doubt the default $content used in this filter is an array, but if it is you should be able to perform the remove_accents() function in a `foreach` loop. It will work.